# What happens to the kinetic energy an electron gains from absorbing a photon with more energy than the bandgap?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, photoelectric-effect

For context, I'm taking a course on quantum mechanics geared towards electrical engineering majors (so basically the standard curriculum, but with additional focus on EE applications, particularly in regards to semiconductor applications, as introductory semiconductor physics is a prereq for the course).  We have a project where we're supposed to compare the energy efficiency of different of solar panels made of materials with different bandgaps.  The underlying theory, according to the professor, is that materials with larger bandgaps are actually more energy efficient because any energy from a photon that's above the bandgap energy is transferred to the electron as kinetic energy, but that this energy is very quickly lost.  I asked him to clarify HOW the energy is lost, i.e., where it goes, and he started talking about the crystal structure of the material and phonons.  But that seems rather like a non sequitur to me -- isn't crystal structure an emergent property at a higher level of abstraction than QM? I don't understand what it has to do with these interactions between photons and electrons.

Specifically what I want to understand is, given an interaction between a single photon and a single electron inside an arbitrary semiconductor, where the photon's energy is greater than the semiconductor's bandgap, after the electron absorbs the photon and moves from the valence band to the conduction band, what actually happens to the additional energy it gained, above that needed to move to the valence band, such that it's considered "lost"?  I don't see how it can get transferred to either other electrons, or the atomic nuclei, since electrons repel each other and they can't directly interact with nuclei, precisely because of quantized energy levels.  Am I misunderstanding something about the interactions between electrons?  Or *does* this relate to crystal structure in some way, as my professor suggested? If so, how? Clearly he's more knowledgeable about the subject than I am, so I figure he's probably ultimately correct, even if he did a poor job explaining.

I'm rather confused about this, but I'm also really curious and I want to understand, so any help in understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mainly electron-electron scattering, and it happens quite fast.